# How to make jQuery validation plugin play nice with jQuery spinner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

So I'm using a jQuery spinner, and I want it to be validated with the jQuery validation plugin.  The spinner is in the form "form", and the code looks like this:

```
jQuery("#mySpinner").spinner({
    min: 110,
    max: 350,
    step: 10,
    spin: function() {jQuery("form").valid();}
});

jQuery("form").validate({
  rules:{
    mySpinner: {required: true, min: 150, max: 350}
  }
});
```

I am calling the jQuery("form").valid() on spin, because when the spinner spins, the validation isn't happening.  That would be the end of my problem, but unfortunately the validation happens before the value is changed in the spinner.  Here is the scenario:

User types 1111 into the spinner.  Validation kicks in on the 4th 1 (since the max in .validate is set to 350), and lets the user know that the input is invalid.  The user then clicks on the down arrow.  First, the validation fires, and the value is flagged as invalid.  Next, the value inside of the spinner is changed to the max value (350, from spinner's "max" value).  What I am left with is a valid value that is flagged as invalid.  If I click the spinner again, it validates with the new value and the invalid flag goes away.

Can someone tell me how to get the validation check to happen *after* the value changes in that spinner?  For that matter, if there is a more obvious and easy solution, could you call it out?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the TimeScaleStartAndEnd sample from http://demos.radiantq.com/jQueryGanttDemo/demo.htm. They have code tab to view the html code. Hope that sample will help you.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?  I don't see anything in there that appears to be addressing my problem.

Comment: This sample will help you to know more about this http://btburnett.com/spinner/example/example.html

Answer (score 0):

I managed to trigger the validation *after* the value changes in the spinner by doing this:

```
jQuery(".ui-spinner").mouseup(function() {jQuery("form").valid();});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that using the 'change' event instead of the 'spin' event would solve your problem. ie,

```
jQuery("#mySpinner").spinner({
    min: 110,
    max: 350,
    step: 10,
    change: function() {jQuery("form").valid();}
});
```

Comment: or the 'stop' method is a good one too. It gets triggered after a spin, while 'change' is triggered when the value of the spinner has changed and the input is no longer focused.